# Manipulating a list using pattern-matching

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I want to write a function which takes a list as input value and manipulates it the following way:

Step 1: Put every 3 elements of the list in a sublist. 
Should there remain less then 3 elements the remaining elements are put together in a specific sublist which is not going to be relevant in Step 2.

Step 2: Reverse the order of the elements in the created sublists. 
The first element should be placed at the position of the third element, the second at the position of first element and the third element at the position of the second element. ([1,2,3] transformed to [2,3,1])

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17] 

-- should be transformed to 
[[2,3,1],[5,6,4],[8,9,7],[11,12,10],[14,15,13],[16,17]]
```

So far I found the following approach to put every 3 elements together in sublists but I am not quite sure how to change the order of the elements in every sublist to match the requirements.

```
    splitEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    splitEvery _ [] = []
    splitEvery n xs = as : splitEvery n bs 
        where (as,bs) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: You can use a separate function that reverses the elements of a list of length three. It will simply return a list of any other list without modification.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` to `[2,3,1]` is a rotation, not a reversal (which would be `[3,2,1]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inner lists are always 3 elements, then you can hardcode that fact and use a simple solution like this:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (x1:x2:x3:xs) = [x2,x3,x1]:f xs
f xs = [xs]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using take and drop as well

```
f [] = []
f xs = (take 3 xs) : f2 (drop 3 xs)
```

Comment: This only addresses step 1.

Answer (score -1):

Idiomatic Haskell would be much better than other answers here. Basically, try to always design the API so it contains the proof that no corner case could occur. Hardcoding literals or hardcoding flip-like operations on lists (without guarantees of its length) are ALWAYS BAD.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

divide : [a] -> [Either [a] (a,a,a)]
divide = \case
    []          -> []
    t1:t2:t3:ts -> Right (t1,t2,t3) : divide ts
    ts          -> [Left ts]

process :: [Either [a] (a,a,a)] -> [[a]]
process = fmap (flatten . flipEls) where
    flipEls = fmap $ \(t1,t2,t3) -> [t2,t1,t3]
    flatten = either id id
```

Now, you can just it like `process . divide`

Comment: Did you even test this? It's full of errors. 1. Syntax error: `:` instead of `::` after `divide`. 2. You use `\case` without enabling the LambdaCase extension. 3. You use `mapRight` from a third-party library that you don't bother to mention. 4. `process` doesn't type-check (you're calling `concat` and shouldn't be).

Comment: @JosephSible, actually nope, I was writing it from a phone waiting for a train. Thanks for catching `:` instead of `::` and unnecessary `concat`.  The rest (lambdacase and mapRight) is easily googleable.